# Smart Contract Withdrawal Function Not Working Properly

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

For some reason my function keeps throwing at 2nd line, where I'm declaring an uint256 named depositedContribution, I have no idea why and I've tried to debug it for hours with no results, what could be the problem with that particular line?

```
function withdraw() external stateRequired(State.OPEN) {
            require(contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contribution > 0);

            uint256 depositedContribution = contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contribution.add(contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contributionFee);

            fees = fees.sub(contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contributionFee);
            size = size.sub(depositedContribution);

            contributions--;

            msg.sender.transfer(depositedContribution);

            contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contributionFee = 0;
            contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contribution = 0;
            contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contributed = false;

            emit ContributionWithdrawn(msg.sender, this, depositedContribution);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `SafeMath` library. The [add](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) function contains a `assert` statement, which reverts the transaction when an overflow happens.

You should check the values of `contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contribution` and `contributorData[address(msg.sender)].contributionFee` and find out if the total of those values is bigger than `2^256-1`, which is the largest value a `uint` can contain

Comment: That's not the issue

Comment: can a struct be too big?

Answer (score 0):

1) I do not see any reason to cast msg.sender to “address”. Use it directly.

2) Check if your safemath has “add” or “sum”

3) make a run using ‘+’ instead of ‘add’ in order to understand if you have overflow or safemath errors

Hope this can help!